# Problems with Automapper Map.CreateMap without Custom Mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I'm trying to use AutoMapper without resorting to custom mapping.

I have two objects defined as follows using the same interface

```
public class Order : IOrder
...

public class OrderViewModel : IOrder
...
```

My Global.asax, looks like this:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<OrderViewModel, Order>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<IOrder, OrderViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<OrderViewModel, IOrder>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<Order, IOrder>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<IOrder, Order>();

        Mapper.CreateMap<IOrder, IOrder>();           

        ...
    }
```

Later on, when I try to use this map, I get an object back, but it has nothing in it.

```
OrderViewModel vm = new OrderViewModel();
vm.OrderName = "Test";

var dto = Mapper.Map<Order, OrderViewModel)(vm);

dto.OrderName = empty string!?!
```

**UPDATE**: I use the map like this actually... Sorry reversed the params.  Anyhow, still doesn't work.

```
var dto = Mapper.Map<OrderViewModel, Order)(vm);
```

Comment: Do both the OrderViewModel & Order have a property called OrderName? Also, I think you should only need:  Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderViewModel>();

Comment: Yes, they both have OrderName.  The interface specifies an OrderName, so the two classes implement that.

Comment: Could you post the actual classes?

Comment: assert the mappings. see if that gives you any errors.

Comment: from looking at it, it would seem that the rules that map to the interface don't make sense. how can automapper (using reflection) create an instance of IOrder if it does not know the implementing class (i.e. Mapper.CreateMap<Order, IOrder>())

Answer (score 0):

The Mapper.Map signature is

```
Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>
```

As you are trying to create an Order here there from an OrderViewModel the view model is the source and the Order is the destination, try swapping the generic arguments to:

```
var dto = Mapper.Map<OrderViewModel, Order)(vm);
```

Comment: Sorry --that was a type-o.  I had it the other way around actually.